# Usar label no lugar do href

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tenho o seguinte css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    border: rgb(0,0,0) 1px solid;
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border: rgb(0,0,0) 1px solid;
}
ul li a {
    display: none;
}
ul li label {
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 3px;
    border: rgb(0,0,0) 1px solid;
    background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
}
ul li a:hover + label {
    outline: rgb(33,180,208) 4px solid;
    background-color: #F00;
    border-color: #CCC;
}
```

E o html

```
<ul>
  <li> <a href="?linkA" name="linkA" id="linkA"></a>
    <label for="linkA">linkA</label>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="?linkB" name="linkB" id="linkB"></a>
    <label for="linkB">linkB</label>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="?linkC" name="linkC" id="linkC"></a>
    <label for="linkC">linkC</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Meu objetivo é esconder o `href` e usar o `label` em forma de `bloco` para dar um `estilo` ao `link`.

Porém quando clico no `label` não está disparando o `href`.

Onde estou errando?

Comment: Porque não aplicas o estilo diretamente no link em vez disso?!

Comment: Você pode ou utilizar o css diretamente no link, ou através de Javascript disparar o gatilho do click no link ao clicar no label.

Comment: verdade. mas para efeito didático, porque não funcionou  no link como acontece com type text?

Comment: A tag <a> não é uma elemento rotulável, então a label não consegue referencia-lo, a lista dos elementos rotuláveis pode ser obtida aqui https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Form_labelable

Comment: entendi: obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca o estilo no link.

```
ul li a {
display: block;
width: 80%;
height: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 3px;
border: rgb(0,0,0) 1px solid;
background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
}
ul li a:hover + a {
outline: rgb(33,180,208) 4px solid;
background-color: #F00;
border-color: #CCC;
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!